# name unicode not defined python3

Tags: pyqt4, python-3.4, python-unicode

i have been trying to run this code
this is the error

```
 File "C:/hari/Academics/python/py programs/gui qt4/book/calculator.py", line 27, in updateUi
    text = unicode(self.lineedit.text(),'utf-8')
NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined
```

the code :

```
from __future__ import division
from math import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import sys

class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent =None):
    super(Form,self).__init__(parent)
    self.browser =QTextBrowser()
    self.lineedit =QLineEdit("type an exp")
    self.lineedit.selectAll()
    layout=QVBoxLayout()
    layout.addWidget(self.browser)
    layout.addWidget(self.lineedit)
    self.setLayout(layout)
    self.lineedit.setFocus()
    self.connect(self.lineedit, SIGNAL("returnPressed()"), self.updateUi)
    self.setWindowTitle("Calculate")
def updateUi(self):
    try:
        text = unicode(self.lineedit.text())
        print(type(text))
        self.browser.append(text+" = <b>"+eval(text)+"</b>" )

    except:
        self.browser.append("<font color=red>"+ text + " is invalid</font>")
app=QApplication(sys.argv)
f=Form()
f.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: By the way: 1) **never** use a bare `except:`. Always specify which exception you want to catch, otherwise it will catch even `KeyboardInterrupt` and can also easily hide bugs. 2) **never** call `eval` on text inserted by the user. If you want to convert the text to a number use `int(text)` or `float(text)`. If you want to allow any kind of *literal* use `literal_eval` from the `ast` package.

Answer (score 7):

in python 3 strings are unicode by default.

Remove the `unicode` function, replace by `str`.

https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit

There's also a little recipe to make the code python 2 & 3 compatible:

```
try:
    unicode        # check if unicode is defined
except NameError:  # not found: python 3: replace by str
    unicode = str
```

Like Bakuriu said in his comment, never use a bare except:

Prefer:

```
except Exception as e:
    print("Problem "+repr(e))
    # the line below requires some HTML normalization or resulting
    # html could be incorrect
    import re
    ne = re.sub("[^\w]"," ",str(e))
    self.browser.append("<font color=red>"+ne+"</font>")
```

Now you have the real/next exception displayed.

Comment: You don't need `unicode` or `str` when using Python 3 with PyQt, since `QString` is automatically converted to a python string. Just do: `text = self.lineedit.text()`.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are using Python 3 , so please replace

`Unicode` function with String `Str` function.

```
def updateUi(self):
    try:
        text = str(self.lineedit.text())  ##replaced here
```